# Two circles and Four circles inside a regular hexagoan

Tags: geometry, circles

Problem Link: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1228

[image]

given the side of the regular hexagon. We have to find the radius of the circles in the above four cases in the picture.

can't find the 2nd and 4th case...

1st case: is six equlatiral triangle and the area is sqrt(3)/4*side^2 = 1/2*side*height.
so height =sqrt(3)/2*side

3rd case : is  2*height =sqrt(3)/2*side
so height = (sqrt(3)/2*side)/2

here height is the radius.
now I need to find the radius of circle in the 2nd and fourth case and in all case circle have the same radius.

Comment: how can I show the picture instead of  link

Comment: I don't have enough teputation for that and I've done it for you.

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: For case 2. Draw radius connecting the center with point in which hexagon is tangent to the circle. Thus find distance of the circle center to the closest hexagon edge...

Comment: sorry don't understand the case 2.

Comment: I'm in a hurry now. I'll sketch a solution later, If no one else does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the side of the hexagon as $a$:

**Case 2:**

[image]

The distance $H$ between parallel sides of the hexagon is $a\sqrt3$. On the other side (look at the picture):

$$H=a\sqrt3=r+(2r)\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+r=r(2+\sqrt3)$$

So the radius of the circle is:

$$r=\frac{a\sqrt3}{2+\sqrt3}=a(2\sqrt3-3)\approx0.464a$$

**Case 4:**

[image]

First equation:

$$PQ=PB+AB\cos\alpha+AD\cos\alpha+DQ$$

$$2a=2\frac{2r\sqrt3}{3}+2(2r)\cos\alpha$$

$$a=\frac{2r\sqrt3}{3}+2r\cos\alpha$$

$$a-\frac{2r\sqrt3}{3}=2r\cos\alpha\tag{1}$$

Second equation:

$$EF=EA+AD\sin\alpha+DC\sin\alpha+CF$$

$$a\sqrt3=2r+2(2r)\sin\alpha$$

$$\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}=r+2r\sin\alpha$$

$$\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}-r=2r\sin\alpha\tag{2}$$

Square (1) and (2) and add to eliminate $\alpha$:

$$(a-\frac{2r\sqrt3}{3})^2+(\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}-r)^2=4r^2$$

This is a simple quadratic equation with two solutions but only one of them is positive:

$$r=a\frac{6\sqrt7-7\sqrt3}{10}\approx0.375a$$

Comment: Lots of thanks I understand the 2nd case ...first I try to solve 4th case my own then I see  yours...thanks a lot.

Comment: @Md.RaihanurRahman If you like the answer, consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: yeah I did that...thank